# Choosing Google autocomplete suggestions without moving my hands from the home row

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autocomplete, google-search

When I'm searching `google.com` and get autocomplete suggestions I use the `down` keyboard key to choose one.

This causes me to move my hands from the home row and wastes too much time. Is there another keyboard shortcut for choosing a suggestion for which I won't need to move my hands from the home row?

Comment: Google Instant only has a few shortcuts: http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/web/Google-Instant-Search.html If you want to create custom ones that would require separate software and manually mapping something, like AutoHotkey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since from the keyboard's "home row" you just can just access to characters, and those are recognized as input for the search field, I'd say no, you can't choose any suggestion without moving to the arrow keys.

But, in case you use Google Chrome, you could write directly on the address bar, and move between the suggestions using the `TAB` key, which would be just extending your little finger.

Comment: Thanks, I use that option on Chrome as well. This issue still applies when I want to continue a previous query, and this happens in the browser window rather than the address bar.

Comment: I'll mark this answer as accepted for now. If someone will find a solution I will update it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently on Ubuntu I'm using [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey-py3/autokey-py3) for mapping `Down Key` to `Ctrl + J` and `Up Key` to `Ctrl + K`.

I use these mappings to traverse the Google autocomplete results.